# DateTime::createFromFormat How to capture a specific date-time?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

How would I use DateTime::createFromFormat to capture both the start and end times for a date like this:

```
Sunday, March 29, 2015<br />10:00 AM - 12:00 PM
```

I need to reformat it for MySQL's DATETIME data type. Here is my attempt:

```
$start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, M d, Y*/*h:i A+', $element->plaintext);
$end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, M d, Y?????????????????h:i A+', $element->plaintext);
$start_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I get the error " Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean..." This must mean that `$element->plaintext` is not what I think it is.

Comment: For your convenience here is `DateTime::createFromFormat`'s usage: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: You'd have to first parse this into 3 strings.  The date, the start time, and the end time.  Then call `createFromFormat` twice, making sure to concat each time to the date.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, really? Then what is the point of the wildcard options? Or am I misusing them?

Comment: Do I use `preg_match` to parse it?

Comment: I didn't actually know `createFromFormat` had wildcard operators.  What if you did something like: `'D, M d, Y*- h:i A'`?

Comment: That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard and separator characters for `DateTime` are a little weird.  First off, the `*` won't match a space character, and you also can't use `*` to match numbers.

So, you need to do this:

```
$start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, M d, Y* *h:i A+', $element->plaintext);
$end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, M d, Y* *h:i A| - h:i A', $element->plaintext);
```

The `|` character in the 2nd example *resets* the date string so it can parse the second time.

DEMO: https://eval.in/306698

Comment: Hmm... I try to put `$start_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` into an array, and I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean ..."

Comment: Is `$element->plaintext` not a string?

Comment: @EinionReishus: What does `var_dump($element->plaintext);` show?

Comment: Interesting, my `var_dump` says it's empty. I'm trying to get the location information in the `<br>` tag at http://www.anthro.ucla.edu/events All I get is `string '

' (length=2)`