# How do I create from format an ISO 8601 date with milliseconds in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to parse the date `2018-07-17T17:34:08.167` into a `DateTimeImmutable` object in my code, which I tried to do with:

```
\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('c', $s);
```

However, because of the milliseconds present and the lack of the time zone, PHP returns `false` for this.

I then tried to create it by defining the format myself, but the problem is that `T` is used as a timezone abbreviation.

```
\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('YYYY-mm-ddTHH:ii:ss.v', $s);
\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('YYYY-mm-dd\\THH:ii:ss.v', $s);
```

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29357265/904344) and tried wildcards, but no dice.

```
\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('YYYY-mm-dd*HH:ii:ss.v', $s);
```

Anyone know how I can get this to parse?

EDIT: That moment when you spend a whole week [coding in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1) and then forget how to format in PHP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use 4 times `Y` (`YYYY`), because `Y` represent year in 4 digits. Same for other "time-markers".

```
$s='2018-07-17T17:34:08.167';
var_dump(\DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v', $s));
```

Output:

```
object(DateTimeImmutable)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-07-17 17:34:08.167000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Paris"
}
```

Comment: Oh my God, I spent the entire last week of the year working on C# and forgot how to code in PHP. What a noob mistake, thanks.